# A square matrix $M$ is invertible if and only if $O$ is not an eigenvalue of $M$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I already know that

a matrix $A$ is not invertible if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue of
$A$

Is true, so does that mean that the opposite "A square matrix A is invertible if and only if $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$" is also true?

Comment: Nevermind, I have determined that the statement is true

Comment: if a statement is true, so is its contrapositive. use this to show its true.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I used!